# firebase read .on('value') not working

Tags: firebase

This script is not working for me.

I know the problem is in the `.on('value')` function but I don't know what it is.

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//dynamic content switching inside the content section
function writeContent(page){
    //setting post to default error message
    var post = "Sorry, This page is undergoing maintenance.";
    //firebase data reference for the clicked link's content
    var dataRef = new Firebase("https://cityartist.firebaseio.com/"+page);
    //inserting the available content to the 'post' variable 
    dataRef.on("value",function(snapshot){
        if(snapshot.val() != null){
            post = snapshot.val();
            alert("post="+post);
        }   
    });
    //showing content in the content section and changing the page's title
    $("#content").append("<article class='post'><p>"+post+"</p></article>");
    $("title").text("CityArtist.org - "+page);
}

//switching pages using the navigation bar
$(".menu_link").click(function(){
    writeContent($(this).attr("name"));
});
 });
```

Comment: @Michael Vayvala: Please use markdown, ie surround code with \`\` instead of using `<code>` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callbacks in Firebase are often fired asynchronously, since Firebase has to wait for the data to arrive.  So your on('value') callback code is being called /after/ the "//showing content in ..." code.  You could try this instead:

```
dataRef.on("value",function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.val() != null){
        post = snapshot.val();
        alert("post="+post);
    }
    //showing content in the content section.
    $("#content").append("<article class='post'><p>"+post+"</p></article>");
});
```

Comment: so how can i use firebase to show different data based on which button the user clicked?

what im trying to do is a dynamic content section in my HTML that changes the text when different nav menu buttons are clicked.

Comment: @user -- See my answer for this fix in context. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the DOM changes inside the callback (e.g. after Firebase has returned data). Here it is in context:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//dynamic content switching inside the content section
function writeContent(page){
    //setting post to default error message
    var post = "Sorry, This page is undergoing maintenance.";
    //firebase data reference for the clicked link's content
    var dataRef = new Firebase("https://cityartist.firebaseio.com/"+page);
    //inserting the available content to the 'post' variable 
    dataRef.on("value",function(snapshot){
        if(snapshot.val() != null){
            post = snapshot.val();
            alert("post="+post);
            //showing content in the content section and changing the page's title
            $("#content").append("<article class='post'><p>"+post+"</p></article>");
            $("title").text("CityArtist.org - "+page);
        }   
    });
}

//switching pages using the navigation bar
$(".menu_link").click(function(){
    writeContent($(this).attr("name"));
});
 });
```